# Is there a way to clear the Zeus/Stingray cache without using SOAP

Tags: linux, cache, zeus

There is an example here of how to clear the content cache in Stingray using the SOAP api

https://splash.riverbed.com/docs/DOC-1238

However, I know that Stingray does write a lot of things to flat files so I was curious if it was possible to brute force a cache clear by clearing the contents of a directory somewhere.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting around version 9.0, there is a REST API as well.

The only other method I know of (other than one of the two APIs) is in the web interface... Go to Activity / Content Cache. There you can search for a Host: and URL path, and there's clear buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a CLI interface that can be used.

Documentation for the CLI can be found on page 348 of the manual for version 9.5